# Workflow symfony 3.2 how search by place

Tags: workflow, symfony

I have set up a workflow state machine and the data is stored in `json_array`. I based myself on [this tutorial](http://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/symfony-workflow-component/).

```
/**
 * This property is used by the marking store
 * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
 */
public $currentPlace;
```

Now I want to search for all open tickets. How to do? Storing with something other than a json_array?

Comment: Is there any reason to use a json_array specifically? Are you storing more than one state at a time? I just repurposed a status field I already had which was a varchar() and then in config.yml just set that field:             type: 'workflow' 
            marking_store:
                type: 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - status

Comment: Yes, you're right 
A simple is enough